# Purpose of scan.TheCallingAssembly, scan.WithDefaultConventions in StructureMap-MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, structuremap, nuget

When adding the [StructureMap-MVC3](https://nuget.org/packages/StructureMap-MVC3) package to an ASP.NET MVC application, 
an `IoC` class containing an `Initialize` method gets added (that gets called by some code in the App_Start folder) containing the following:

```
public static class IoC
{
    public static IContainer Initialize()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
            {
                x.Scan(scan =>
                    {
                        scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                        scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                    });
                // x.For<IExample>().Use<Example>();
            });
        return ObjectFactory.Container;
    }
}
```

What is the purpose of the `scan.TheCallingAssembly()` and `scan.WithDefaultConventions()` code? I can't see a good explanation of these methods in the [StructureMap documentation](http://docs.structuremap.net/ScanningAssemblies.htm#section1).

When using StructureMap in a non-MVC project I've found that the whole `x.Scan` section can be removed without having any impact.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Scanning looks at all the types defined in your Assembly, and applies StructureMap conventions to determine if/how they should be registered in the container.

`WithDefaultConventions` means: "if while scanning I find an interface `IExample`, and there is a type `Example` that implements `IExample`, then register `Example` as the default type for `IExample`".

In many cases, you will be able to ask the container for whatever you are looking for (`IExample`), and it will return an implementation, without any further configuration.